# Cannot correct a failed migration django

Tags: django, postgresql, model

I inadvertently did this:

```
ordering = models.IntegerField(default="Order/position")
```

I ran `makemigrations` and got no error. When I ran `migrate` it blew up with the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Order/position'
```

what I had meant to do was this:

```
ordering = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Order/Position")
```

I updated to the correct field definition and while `makemigrations` is happy and noted the change `migrate` still keeps throwing that same error.

How do I fix this?

In case this matters - I am running Django with Postgres and both are in Docker containers

Is it possible to "cancel" a previously failed migration?
Is it common for makemigration to not catch big errors like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is probably to fix the migration file itself. In the migration file, it will probably looked like:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        # …
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                (
                    'id',
                    models.AutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name='ID',
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    'ordering',
                    models.IntegerField(
                        default='Order/position',
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        )
    ]
```

You fix this by altering the definition for `ordering` to the `IntegerField` you described.

Comment: I thought manually editing migrations was to be avoided? Newb question sorry

Comment: @tanbog: mainly removing... Fixing migrations that are nonsensical is not a problem. Sometimes you even create data migrations where you construct migrations yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: What is to be avoided is rewriting a valid migration, since that might already have been done on some databases. But here it will of course never work.